# Calculate distance from Location - iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-location

I'm trying to calculate the distance between two places user Core Location. I've found a few posts that state to use

```
-(CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

Found some other test code in the thread below:

[CLLocationDistance NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171138/cllocationdistance-nan)

I'm not sure how to put it all together, to get the result I want ?

Anyone any thoughts ?

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a location named `myLocation` and want to find the distance from another location, say, `restaurantLocation`, then it seems you would do something like

```
CLLocationDistance distance = [myLocation distanceFromLocation:restaurantLocation]
```

This will give you the distance, in meters, between the two.

Comment: Dc, thanks for the response. In the example above what exactly does myLocation contain. Is it the longitude and latitude of my current location. Could you please explain.

Comment: Dc, please ignore the comment above, I got around this problem.